# Pass COM VBA List of objects to C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I'm trying to pass list of objects from Excel VBA to C# function.

C# Function

```
public object[] InsertVbaList(object[] vbaList)
{
    return vbaList;
}
```

VBA Call

```vb
Sub SendVbaList()
   Dim arrIns(1) As Variant
   Dim arrRes As Variant
   Dim DLL As MyDll.Func
   Dim OBJ() As Variant
   Set DLL = New MyDll.Func

   Set OBJ = New MyDll.Object
   OBJ.String = "A"
   OBJ.Int = 1
   arrIns(0) = OBJ

   Set OBJ = New MyDll.Object
   OBJ.String = "B"
   OBJ.Int = 2
   arrIns(1) = OBJ
   arrRes = DLL.InsertVbaList(arrIns)
End Sub
```

Unfortunately VBA does not recognize C# `object[]`, err:

> Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

Any ideas how to do it?

Thanx in advance

Comment: There is an ambiguity about an array of variants.  I think the VBA runtime wants to pass that as a variant that stores an array of variants.  The MSDN docs for the VariantWrapper class talk about this.  That is object and not object[] on the C# side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Рен, you were close.

True, C# does not recognized variant array. I had to specyfy type of array on VBA side.
And also one small thing; i added before parameter in C# function word ref (i have no idea for why, it's making object[] array visible in VBA).

Now code look like below:

C#

```
public object[] InsertVbaList(ref object[] vbaList)
{
    return vbaList;
}
```

VBA

```
Sub SendVbaList()
   Dim arrIns(1) As MyDll.Object
   Dim arrRes As Variant
   Dim DLL As MyDll.Func
   Dim OBJ As MyDll.Object
   Set DLL = New MyDll.Func
   Set OBJ(1) = New MyDll.Object

   OBJ(0).String = "A"
   OBJ(0).Int = 1    
   OBJ(1).String = "B"
   OBJ(1).Int = 2

   arrRes = DLL.InsertVbaList(arrIns)
   Debug.Print(Ubound(arrRes))
End Sub
```

I hope it will help to someone.